# postfix: check_client_access not working

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I want to block specific IP's, that try to login to my postfix server by smtpd. Therefore in the /etc/postfix/main.cf I added the following:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
    ...
    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist
```

My /etc/postfix/blacklist looks like that:

```
185.40.4.32     REJECT dont want spammers
80.82.78.96     REJECT dont want spammers
74.208.72.135   REJECT dont want spammers
```

Of course I created a /etc/postfix/blacklist.db by the command

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/blacklist
```

and restartet postfix.

But in /var/log/mail.log still the following appears:

```
Aug 28 13:32:08 server postfix/smtpd[5035]: warning: hostname hosted-by.hostgrad.ru does not resolve to address 185.40.4.32
Aug 28 13:32:08 server postfix/smtpd[5035]: connect from unknown[185.40.4.32]
Aug 28 13:32:13 server postfix/smtpd[5035]: warning: unknown[185.40.4.32]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Aug 28 13:32:13 server postfix/smtpd[5035]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.40.4.32]
Aug 28 13:32:13 server postfix/smtpd[5035]: disconnect from unknown[185.40.4.32]
```

So obviously the client with the IP 185.40.4.32 still is not blocked. Does anybody have an idea, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With...

```
smtpd_delay_reject = no
```

it works. 
But think about this:

> SMTP command specific restrictions that are described under the smtpd_helo_restrictions, smtpd_sender_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameters. When helo, sender or recipient restrictions are listed under smtpd_client_restrictions, they have effect only with "smtpd_delay_reject = yes", so that $smtpd_client_restrictions is evaluated at the time of the RCPT TO command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to use the `.db` format.  I got successful REJECT when I used `.cidr` format. Like this:

```
check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/spammer_ip.cidr
```

Use this format for your `.cidr` records:

```
185.40.4.32     REJECT dont want spammers
```

Comment: I tried that already  - only successful if "smtpd_delay_reject = no" is set.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue before and solved by adding at the end of `main.cnf` the following line

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

Dont forget to

```
postmap /etc/postifx/access
```